# The distributed cache service instance

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, distributedcache

I got the below error

**Distributed cache service is not enabled in this deployment.**

I did `Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance`
the old error run a way and the below one come  :(

Error

**Distributed cache service is unexpected configured on server(s**
The distributed cache service instance should not be configured for the failing servers. Remove the distributed cache service instances from the failing servers.

Comment: How many servers u have in the farm? on which server it is enabled? what is the status of the DC, is it up or down?

Comment: 2 application server , the first server , stopped , down :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basically DC is not provisioned properly.I would do following steps.

- Login on the server with Farm administrator account.
- Run this

  $instanceName =”SPDistributedCacheService Name=AppFabricCachingService” 
  $serviceInstance = Get-SPServiceInstance | ? {($*.service.tostring()) -eq $instanceName -and ($*.server.name) -eq $env:computername}

  $serviceInstance.Unprovision() 
  $serviceInstance.Delete()
- Run `Remove-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance`, Once it completed sucessfully
- Verfiry the AppFabric Service is stopped...Check from Service console on the server, Also check from the Central admin ? system setting > manage Service on server. Make sure both says Stopped in front of DC.
- Now Run the `Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance`
- Wait for couple of minutes and Now check the Status of the DC. Run these commands. `Use-CacheCluster` followed by `Get-CacheHost`.

this is good article for the reference: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sambetts/2014/03/19/sharepoint-2013-distributed-cache-appfabric-troubleshooting/

**Edit:**

try this

```
$instanceName =”SPDistributedCacheService Name=AppFabricCachingService” 
$serviceInstance = Get-SPServiceInstance | ? {($_.service.tostring()) -eq $instanceName -and ($_.server.name) -eq $env:computername}

If($seriveInstance -ne $null)
{
$serviceInstance.Delete()
}
```

Comment: Unprovision()  not worked null PS :environment is 2016

Comment: try the new script, i just mentioned above... after that run this...Get-SPServiceInstance | ? {($_.service.tostring()) -eq “SPDistributedCacheService Name=AppFabricCachingService”} | select Server, Status

Comment: please help me :( :(

Comment: Ca or Distributed cache?

Comment: This command is only for D.C. Not related to ca. Try to run Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance

Comment: both, app fabric is stoped and not started it give access denied

Comment: For which account,how you starting it?

Comment: farm account :(

Comment: CA give 500 internal error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57856/discussion-between-aashirya-and-waqas-sarwar-mvp).

Comment: please help!!!!!